# How do I get the airborne memory token near M-013?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

On Kronos Island there is a memory token suspended in the air. The token is located east of the yellow chaos emerald, above challenge M-013 and next to a loop-de-loop grind rail. There's a midair ring that would launch me to the token, but I can't figure out how to reach it.

How do I get the midair memory token near M-013?

[image: memory token with a red circle]

Answer (score 2):

Run towards the tower and there's a ramp at the base facing back towards the big rail that resembled the Arch in St. Louis. It's pretty straight forward from there. ^^
[image: You're welcome!]